# Unable to subtract two sets containing two dictonaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

// compare two arrays getting result same as first set

```
    let preContactSet = Set(arrayLiteral: tempPreviousContactArray )
    let currentContactSet = Set(arrayLiteral: tempCurrentContactArray)
    let subtractSet =  currentContactSet.intersect(preContactSet)
    print(subtractSet)
```

Comment: Do you have a bit more code, maybe containing those dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract two set using following code.
Try this hope it will help you.

```
let test1 : NSArray = NSArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
let test2 : NSArray = NSArray(array: [4, 3])
let set1 : NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet(array: test1 as [AnyObject])
let set2:NSSet = NSSet(array: test2 as [AnyObject])
set1.intersectSet(set2 as Set<NSObject>)
print(set1.allObjects)
```